# Externalities from motor vehicles - more recent estimates?

Tags: reference-request, externalities, research

I am looking for estimates for the externalities from motor vehicles.

There's an excellent paper "Automobile Externalities and Policies" ([2007](https://www.aeaweb.org/articles?id=10.1257/jel.45.2.373)) on this exact issue, but it's a bit old now.

I was wondering if there was more recent/updated study that does something similar?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Handbook on the External Costs of Transport – Version 2019](https://www.cedelft.eu/en/publications/2311/handbook-on-the-external-costs-of-transport-version-2019)

Commissioned by the European Commission and produced by the research firm CE Delft. I think it was first published in 2008 and had a 2014 update. This is the latest 2019 update.